# How to remove specific portion from a file using awk in a bash script with variables

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file test.txt and I want to remove specific portion in a file.
This is the file:

```
    #######################Part 1 start######################
    text
    #######################Part 1 end#######################
    
    #######################Part 2 start#######################
    text
    #######################Part 2 end#######################
    
    #######################Part 3 start#####################
    text
    #######################Part 3 end#######################
```

Using this awk command in a bash script i can delete a portion of text, for example:

Input:

```
    awk '/^[#]+(Part 2 start)[#]+/{f=1}f && /^[#]+(Part 2 end)[#]+/{f=0; next}!f' test.txt
```

Output:

```
#######################Part 1 start######################
text
#######################Part 1 end#######################

#######################Part 3 start#####################
text
#######################Part 3 end#######################
```

**I would like to use variables inside the awk regex like this:**

```
P="Part 2"
awk '/^[#]+($P start)[#]+/{f=1}f && /^[#]+($P end)[#]+/{f=0; next}!f' test.txt
```

But with this input, the output is the original file without any kind of modification:

```
#######################Part 1 start######################
text
#######################Part 1 end#######################

#######################Part 2 start#######################
text
#######################Part 2 end#######################

#######################Part 3 start#####################
text
#######################Part 3 end#######################
```

Could you help me understand where I'm wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Variables are not expanded by the shell between single quotes. If you want the shell to expand the variables, you have to use double quotes. Otherwise, you can turn the shell variables into awk variables using the `-v` option of awk. If you choose the latter approach, you would first (in awk) build the regexp as a string and then explicitly use the `=~` for matching.

Comment: i tried these commands but neither work. Where am I doing wrong?
1) awk '/^[#]+(start "$nome" alerting rules)[#]+/{f=1}f && /^[#]+(end "$nome" alerting rules)[#]+/{f=0; next}!f' test.txt

2) awk "/^[#]+(start $nome alerting rules)[#]+/{f=1}f && /^[#]+(end $nome alerting rules)[#]+/{f=0; next}!f" test.txt

Comment: You still have a single quote (immediately after the word `awk`), so `$nome` is implicitly also between single quotes. Single quotes bascially tell the shell to not touch what is in between them. They beasically don't care what is betweeen single quotes. In particular, `$` and double quotes between single quotes don't have any effect.

Comment: Must you use awk for this? The task you want to do is basically text exiting and sed is the unix stream text editor. You also should checkout ed which is the command line editor, depending on what you're trying to achieve.